# Timer Tick not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am using ASP.NET Web Forms, but there is a small issue.

I want the form to update every 1 second, but I do not want it to reload the entire page.

After spending most the day Googling, I got this code, however it is still not firing the tick action.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableCdn="True"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="masterTimer" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer ID="masterTimer" runat="server" ontick="masterTimer_Tick" Interval="1000"></asp:Timer>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

All this tick is going to do, is add the current time to a list box. This is where another question comes in. Does the list box need to be wrapped in the above code somehow also, and this is causing the issue?

```
protected void masterTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    priList.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
}
```

Comment: If you're very new to asp.net, don't use this very old and outdated version of asp.net. Upgrade to asp.net MVC or Blazor using .Net 5.

Comment: Oh ok, I just created a WebForm from Visual Studios. I am going to look that up now. Thank you!

Comment: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/learn/aspnet/hello-world-tutorial/intro

Comment: Yes, web forms were pretty cool back in 2003.  They are pretty aged right now

Comment: Do you ever call `masterTimer.Start();` or set `masterTimer.Enabled = true;`?

Comment: @RufusL .Enabled = True yes. Now that I think about the start, I am second guessing myself... I will check in a moment... Installing new .Net, figured either way, thats a good step.

Comment: @RufusL ok checked my code, and I remember I tried masterTime.Start(); but it is not a variable within asp.net, but by default the masterTimer is enabled. And just for the heck of it, I set it to be via the Page_load also, with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was, I did not have the item(s) (ie Listbox) within the ContentTemplate

```
<asp:Timer runat="server" id="priTimer" interval="5000" ontick="priTimer_Tick" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="TimedPanel" updatemode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="priTimer" eventname="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
             <asp:ListBox ID="priList" runat="server" style="font-size: 1vw; OVERFLOW:auto; width:100%"></asp:ListBox>
        </ContentTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the timer outside of the UpdatePanel and making the UpdateMode conditional.

```
<asp:Timer ID="masterTimer" Interval="1000" runat="server" OnTick="masterTimer_Tick"></asp:Timer>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        ...
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="masterTimer" EventName="tick" />
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```